# Sending mail using PHP issue

Tags: php, html

Having an issue being able to send mail using PHP I have looked through my code and can't find where I'm going wrong. Edited with my html instered.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['primaryemail'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $phone_numbertwo = $_POST['phone_numbertwo'];
    $primaryemail = $_POST['primaryemail'];


    if (!empty($primaryemail)) {
        $to = 'testemail@gaming.com';
        $subject = 'Jobsite Form Submitted';
        $body = "Submitted by: " . $first_name . "Phone number: " . $phone_number . "Secondary phone number: " . $phone_numbertwo;
        $headers = 'From:' . $primaryemail;
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);   
    }
}
?>

<form name="jobsiteform" class="jobsiteform" method="POST" action="">
<h2>Contact Information</h2>
<h4>Primary Contact Information</h4>
<br>
    <label>Full Name: &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" maxlength="70" placeholder="First & Last" required>
    <br><br>
    <label>Phone Number: &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="phone" maxlength="13" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" required>
    <br><br>
    <label>Secondary Phone Number: &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_numbertwo" id="phone_numbertwo" class="phone" maxlength="13" placeholder="Optional">
    <br><br>
    <label>E-mail: &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="100" id="primaryemail" placeholder="e.g. first.last@domain.com" required>
    <br>
```

Comment: Are you running it through localhost or any live server?

Comment: where is your event and your html?

Comment: It's through a web hosting server.

Comment: Are you getting any error? how are you executing that script?

Comment: Your host likely has a help section dedicated to email that might help for their specific servers.

Comment: I'm receiving no error. I'll check with the host.

Comment: Check the below by @PatrickMurphy, that should resolve your issue. Also `isset($_POST['primaryemail']` then `!empty($primaryemail)` is a bit redundant why not just do a `!empty` check to begin with?

Comment: Thanks @chris85 I too am confident that that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `name=""` not `id=''` in your HTML

You need to modify your html you have the `ID` set to what the `Name` should be on your primary email field. The name parameter is used by the Post request to PHP not ID (often used by javascript).

```
<input type="email" name="primaryemail" maxlength="100" id="primaryemail" placeholder="e.g. first.last@domain.com" required>
```

Therefore your php script never executes due to this line beacuse the post value is set to the key `$_POST['email']` not `$_POST['primaryemail']` therefore it is not set.

```
if (isset($_POST['primaryemail'])){
```

That is why it is a good idea to do an else at the end of that and `echo 'error: post email not sent';`

Comment: Thanks for the tip and finding my error!

Answer (score 1):

Put your PHP code in an extern file, add the path to that file in your `action="path to file"` and add a submit button inside `<form>`. Example: `<input type="submit" value="Send">`.

Comment: It should work either way.